# What's the etiquette for duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, sffaq, duplicates

I just answered a question, and then later someone voted it down and noted that it was a duplicate.

Is there a recommended way for an "answerer" to deal with this?  i.e. if I find that my answer is appropriate for the older question, should I repeat it there?  Or will someone with a higher rep come by and merge the questions?

Comment: Suggestion; add this to the community wiki? It's a good question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/How-to-handle-duplicate-questions

Answer (score 4):

There's no mergening; the question should be voted/flagged as duplicated and people with high rep can edit it with links to the answered questions.

You might as well answer with a link the the answered question while waiting for it to be closed.

Comment: Merging questions is a good option when they're exactly the same and the second question has fetched some answers before it can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I should have thought of this when I posted the question, but it was late...  The StackOverflow answer is here:

[How StackOverflow handles duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610728/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions)

Here's a summary of that answer:

- **Don't** tag duplicate questions with "duplicate"
- A question should only be closed if it's an **exact** duplicate of another question.
- <s>If you have enough rep to edit the question, add the following at the **top** of the question:</s>
  <sup><sub>This now gets automatically added when closing as a duplicate</sub></sup>

  ```
  ###Duplicate
  > [title of question](url to question)
  ```
- If the question is similar to another one, add the following at the **bottom** of the question:

  ```
  ###See also
  > [title of question](url to question)
  ```
- If you can't edit the question, leave a comment with a link to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can answer duplicate questions, the downvoter obviously didn't get the concept of "helpful/not helpful" answers. (Because that's what you say with a vote)

On the other hand you should think twice if it is worth your time and effort to answer a question which is most likely to be closed. (Even more so if SF get's more users with a high enough reputation)